# Resize observer not updating in Alpine.js data

Tags: alpine.js

using resizeObserver, i'm trying to update the data in Alpine.js to display it in the app. Currently it displays the data once but not when the window is resized. [Codpen](https://codepen.io/limitedunlimited/pen/vYrYrWJ)

Code below

```
function app() {
  return {
    init() {
      var ro = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
        for (let entry of entries) {
          console.log(entry);
          this.dimensions.push({
            dim: `${(entry.contentRect.width / 16).toFixed(2)}rem`
          });
        }
      });
      ro.observe(this.$refs.box);
      ro.observe(document.documentElement);
    },
    dimensions: [],
    display: []
  };
}
```

html

```
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="wrapper" x-data="app()">
  <p class="dimension" x-text="dimensions[1].dim"></p>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="dimension" x-text="dimensions[0].dim" x-ref="box"></p>
    <pre class="code">margin-inline: max(0px,((100% - 64rem) / 2))</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adding the observed entry to the end of an array. You would have to `x-text` on that last entry too, meaning your code should look something like this:

```
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="wrapper" x-data="app()">
  <p class="dimension" x-text="dimensions[dimensions.length - 1].dim"></p>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="dimension" x-text="dimensions[dimensions.length - 1].dim" x-ref="box"></p>
    <pre class="code">margin-inline: max(0px,((100% - 64rem) / 2))</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you should just make the `dimension` variable a simple single entry, and override that when something new is observed.